# How to find a files which names start with a certain amount of digits?

Tags: linux, unix

I am trying to locate files by name, ones that start with at least three digits for example.

`find . -type f -name [0-3]*` will find files starting with numbers up to 3, but not with a string of three digits at the start of the name.

Anyone can shed some insight?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want 3 digits, you have to specify you want 3 characters between 0-9

```
find . -type f -name "[0-9][0-9][0-9]*"
```

Comment: Thank you very much! This worked beautifully exactly as needed!