# How to change the output of a command to all UPPERCASE

Tags: linux, bash

What can i do to capitalize all characters in the output of the ifconfig command in Bash?

So what is returned, is all in uppercase letters

Comment: looks like rather an [XY Problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem)
 from https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67520797/how-to-find-a-files-which-names-start-with-a-certain-amount-of-digits

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to convert a string to lower case in Bash?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2264428/how-to-convert-a-string-to-lower-case-in-bash)

Answer (score 2):

You could use [`tr`](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/tr.html) with character classes:

```
ifconfig | tr '[:lower:]' '[:upper:]'
```